# My code (CSS and HTML) Does something weird to the page when i use positon:relative

Tags: html, css

When I use position: relative in my CSS style sheet, I move the words around the page. This works fine. But a bar appears at the bottom. I move it to the right... the whole page moves. The position: relative is what causes this, I'm sure. The body doesn't even reach to this extra part of the page. It only happens on the homepage, the one which I use position: relative on. Here is my code (homepage):

Birdman Home
     

            

    
    
    Home
    About Us
    About Birdman
    History and Future
    Competitors
    Sign Up
    Login
    
    
    **Join us as we try to make the push into the Olympics**
    
    
    
    
    
    Sign Up
    
    Login
    
    *It's Free!*
    
    Rules and how to compete
    
    Reasons you should join
    
    Rules
    
    Reasons

And this is the parts of the style sheet I use:

```
.navBar {
    background-color: aqua;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navBar a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 54.08px;
}

.navBar a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

.navBar a:active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#homeTitle{
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
    position: relative; right: 150px;
}

.tortillaJump{
    position: relative; bottom: 70px;
}

}

body{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.signUp{
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 70px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative; bottom: 500px; left: 420px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.signUp: hover{
    background-color: red;
}

.login{
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 81px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative; bottom: 444px; left: 203px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.login: hover{
    background-color: red;
}

#itsFree{
    position: relative; bottom: 455px; left: 1365px;
}

#ruleTitle{
    position: relative; bottom: 455px; left: 1288px;
    color: white;
}

#reasonTitle{
    position: relative; bottom: 180px; left: 325px;
    color: white;
}

#rules{
    position: relative; bottom: 500px; left: 1375px;
    color: white;    
}

#reasons{
    position: relative; bottom: 220px; left: 390px;
    color: white;
}
```

```css
.navBar {
    background-color:aqua;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navBar a {
    float: left;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 54.08px;
}

.navBar a:hover {
  background-color:red;
  color: black;
}

.navBar a:active {
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}

#homeTitle{
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:white;
    position:relative; right: 150px;
}

.tortillaJump{
    position:relative; bottom: 70px;
}

}

body{
    background-color:blueviolet;
}

.signUp{
    background-color:aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 70px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    position:relative; bottom: 500px; left: 420px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.signUp:hover{
    background-color:red;
}

.login{
    background-color:aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 81px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    position:relative; bottom: 444px; left: 203px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.login:hover{
    background-color:red;
}

#itsFree{
    position:relative; bottom: 455px; left: 1365px;
}

#ruleTitle{
    position:relative; bottom: 455px; left: 1288px;
    color:white;
}

#reasonTitle{
    position:relative; bottom: 180px; left: 325px;
    color:white;
}

#rules{
    position:relative; bottom: 500px; left: 1375px;
    color:white;    
}

#reasons{
    position:relative; bottom: 220px; left: 390px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
        
    <title>Birdman Home</title>
    <link href="Style_Sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

</head>
            
<body>
    
    <div class="navBar">
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_Home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_About-Us.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_About-Birdman.html">About Birdman</a>
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_History-and-Future.html">History and Future</a>
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_Competitors.html">Competitors</a>
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_Signup-and-Login.html">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_Signup-and-Login.html">Login</a>
    </div>
    
    <h1 id="homeTitle"><strong>Join us as we try to make the push into the Olympics</strong></h1>
    
    <!--image source=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D65Dz6fmUQ-->
    
    <img src=Tortilla-Jump.png alt="person in tortilla suit jumping" class="tortillaJump">
    
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_Signup-and-Login.html"><button class="signUp">Sign Up</button></a>
    
    <a href="Birdman_Rally_Signup-and-Login.html"><button class="login">Login</button></a>
    
    <p id="itsFree"><em>It's Free!</em></p>
    
    <h3 id="ruleTitle">Rules and how to compete</h3>
    
    <h3 id="reasonTitle">Reasons you should join</h3>
    
    <p id="rules">Rules</p>
    
    <p id="reasons">Reasons</p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

The snippets are so weird though and It doesn't look like what mine does when I'm on brackets:

[screenshot before moving the bar at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEtN0.png)

[screenshot after (all the way)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGN2P.png)

I hope I got my point across. I use brackets. Does anyone know another way to move the text into an exact position, or a way to still use position: relative but get rid of the weird extra page part? or maybe the spot where the text goes smaller?

Comment: Setting the `left` CSS property will move that element to the left (when relative). This won't effect the actual width of the element. By default, `div` and `p` tags are full width. So by specifying `left: 1375px`, you've just pushed it across without changing the width. Now your page is 1375px wider.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inspect element from chrome to see which element is causing your page to act that way. From there you can modify the style accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).